# Adding new column in the orders grid issue in Magento1

Tags: magento-1, grid

I am using the [Gridcontrol](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl) to add/remove new columns.

This is my XML:

```
<sales_order_grid>
.....
<customer_increment_id>
    <add>
        <header>Customer ID</header>
        <type>text</type>
        <index>customer_increment_id</index>
        <join table="customer/entity" condition="main_table.customer_id={{table}}.entity_id" field="increment_id as customer_increment_id"/>
     </add>
     <after>scheduled_at</after>
</customer_increment_id>
.....
</sales_order_grid>
```

This is the query generated:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `customer/entity`.`increment_id` AS 

`customer_increment_id` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`

INNER JOIN `customer_entity` AS `customer/entity`

ON main_table.customer_id=`customer/entity`.entity_id
```

The query returns me values. I want to get the `customer_increment_id`, but for some reason I m getting empty results in my grid for this column. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Due to the fact that I cannot add an `alias` to my join from XML. I came with the idea to add a renderer, like:

```
 <customer_increment_id>
         <add>
            <header>Customer ID</header>
            <type>text</type>  
            <renderer>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Renderer_Customers</renderer>
         </add>
         <after>scheduled_at</after>
    </customer_increment_id>
```

and this is my block:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Renderer_Customers extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{

    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $customerId = $row->getData('customer_id');
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
        return $customer->getData('increment_id');
    }
}
```